# Can Eclipse launcher ini -configuration variable take a relative path?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an `RCP Eclipse` product that defines the -configuration folder to be in a different location from the `exe` and `ini` files.  When I specify the path to configuration in the `ini` as *relative to the* `exe`, launching the product only works when launched from the directory of the `exe`.

Ie: `/home/Sheldon>product.exe`

Launching *from another directory* **fails**, unless the *configuration path* is set to an *absolute path* in the `ini` file.

Ie: `>/home/Sheldon/product.exe`

This is not the case for the `startup` or `launcher.library` variables.

Is there a way to support this setup with a *relative configuration path*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely like to close my own question without a comment or an anwser, but I did come to a conclusion and I think it is the best answer at this time.

I do not believe this is possible, without modifying the eclipse source.

In particular, [LocationManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse/osgi/3.5.0/org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/LocationManager.java#LocationManager.buildURL%28java.lang.String,boolean%29) : [buildLocation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse/osgi/3.5.0/org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/LocationManager.java#177).

So, the best compromise is to place the `configuration` folder adjacent to the `plugins` folder.  It is fine for the `plugins` folder to be in a relative path.  For example, a valid `product.ini` with these folders in relative path would look like:

```
-startup
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_4.2.0.v20
1201111650
-vm
../jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

This means that the `configuration` folder MUST exist in `../Common/configuration` to have a relative path.  Any other folder will require an absolute path, or usage of one of the less than useful replacement variables, { `@NoDefault`, `@None`, `@user.dir`, `@user.home` }.

Comment: Did you ever report a bug to Eclipse? I am experiencing the same problem as you. It took posting my own question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145365) to see yours in the Related column.

Comment: @StevenDarnell No, I didn't report a bug. I think this might be a nice enhancement, but since the compromise works consistently, I just went with it.

Comment: I submitted an Eclipse bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426189) to address this issue.

Comment: Bug 426189 was fixed and will be part of the Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) release.